# Mixing one-to-many with many-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Sorry the title of this question isn't very good.  I'm not sure how to condense the subject down to a single sentence.

Here's what we start with, pretty simple setup.  Orgs to Taxes are one-to-many.

```
class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Org> Orgs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tax> Taxes { get; set; }
}

class Org
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private List<Tax> taxes;
    public virtual List<Tax> Taxes
    {
        get { return taxes ?? (taxes = new List<Tax>()); }
        protected set { taxes = value; }
    }
}

class Tax
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OrgId { get; set; }
    public virtual Org Org { get; set; }
}
```

This produces the following schema, as expected:

[image: Before]

Now I'd like to add a DefaultTaxId to Orgs.

```
class Org
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private List<Tax> taxes;
    public virtual List<Tax> Taxes
    {
        get { return taxes ?? (taxes = new List<Tax>()); }
        protected set { taxes = value; }
    }

    // default tax added here

    public int? DefaultTaxId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tax DefaultTax { get; set; }
}
```

However when I generate a migration, the C# looks like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Taxes", "OrgId", "dbo.Orgs");
    AddColumn("dbo.Orgs", "DefaultTaxId", c => c.Int());
    AddColumn("dbo.Taxes", "Org_Id", c => c.Int());
    CreateIndex("dbo.Orgs", "DefaultTaxId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Taxes", "Org_Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Orgs", "DefaultTaxId", "dbo.Taxes", "Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Taxes", "Org_Id", "dbo.Orgs", "Id");
}
```

And the schema looks like this:

[image: After]

The `DefaultTaxId` column was added to Orgs as expected, however the Taxes table now has an `Org_Id` column with a foreign key, and the original `OrgId` column is no longer a foreign key.

Why are these extra operations and schema changes happening?  **I think because an Org has a Tax and a Tax has an Org, EF thinks I'm trying to mix a one-to-many with a many-to-many**, but I don't know how to fix it.

How can I just add a DefaultTaxId foreign key to Orgs?

Answer (score 0):

EF can no longer determine the relationships. You can do it with fluent code or here would be the annotations needed:

```
class Tax
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Org")]
    public int OrgId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Taxes")]
    public virtual Org Org { get; set; }
}
```

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s03.html

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent Configuration to do this would be:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Org>().HasMany(o => o.Taxes).WithRequired(t => t.Org);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Org>().HasOptional(o => o.DefaultTax).WithRequired();
}
```